# Enum in Eclipse nosuchmethoderror

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I've been doing TheNewBoston Tutorials on Java but got stuck on Enums and I just can't get around it. Every time I try to compile i get this error Thread [main](Suspended (exception NoSuchMethodError) pointing to line 5 in my Tuna Class. Here is my Tuna class and Apples class.

```
public enum Tuna 
{

bucky("nice", "22"),
kelsey("cutie", "10"),
julia("mistake", "12");


private final String desc;
private final String year;

Tuna(String description, String birthday)
{
    desc = description;
    year = birthday;        
}
public String getDesc()
{
    return desc;
}
public String getYear()
{
    return year;
}

}

public class Apples 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(Tuna people: Tuna.values())
               System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", people, people.getDesc(), people.getYear());
}
}
```

I got no clue what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 if that matter.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFGrL5vyp54&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28
The tutorial in question.

Comment: Have you not forget to close the enumeration with `;`? Like: `julia("mistake", "12");`

Comment: private final Strin year; Perhaps Strin should be String?

Comment: Is this `private final Strin year;` a typo?

Comment: Yes they are all typos. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should paste the entire error. 
Other than that i think the line below needs semi colon in the end

Change this

```
 julia("mistake", "12"),
```

to

```
 julia("mistake", "12");
```

Also your class probably should look like this

```
public class Apples {
    public enum Tuna {
       bucky("nice", "22"),
       kelsey("cutie", "10"),
       julia("mistake", "12");

       private final String desc;
       private final String year;

       Tuna(String description, String birthday) {
          desc = description;
          year = birthday;        
       }

       public String getDesc() {
          return desc;
       }

       public String getYear() {
          return year;
       }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     for(Tuna people: Tuna.values())
           System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", people, people.getDesc(), people.getYear());
   }
}
```

Comment: Apples [Java Application] 
 Apples at localhost:56859 
  Thread [main] (Suspended (Tuna cannot be resolved)) 
   Apples.main(String[]) line: 6 
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java (Mar 11, 2014 9:37:49 PM)

I did add a Semicolon before and It didn't change anything.

Comment: I would like to mention that the code works flawless in Netbeans.

Comment: Tried and did not solve the problem. I really got no clue what could be wrong. I've check the JRE and Compiler Paths and their versions. they are 1.7 and pointed correctly.